# Probably a simple solution - Reset Flickity Slides Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, slider, slideshow, flickity

for my portfolio, I'm using Flickity. On click on the single tiles, a modal with a slider opens. Every trigger opens the same Flickity slider but changes the image src of the cells. So far so good. But if I open the slider with the first trigger and slide eg to slide 2 and close it, trigger 2,3,4 and so on open on slide 2. Due to this, I need to reset the slider or jump to slide 1 when I close the modal. I think this should happen in "hideslider()". I've already tried "flkty.reloadCells();", but it's not working. Thanks a lot for your help.

My **Vanilla** JS

```
//get modal and flickity cells
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
var cell1 = document.getElementById("cell1");
var cell2 = document.getElementById("cell2");
var cell3 = document.getElementById("cell3");
var cell4 = document.getElementById("cell4");

// Slider 01
var trigger1 = document.getElementById("trigger1");
trigger1.onclick = function() {
  cell1.src = "./_mat/gallery2/g2p1.png";
  cell2.src = "./_mat/portfolio_g1_t1_c2.jpg";
  cell3.src = "./_mat/portfolio_g1_t1_c3.jpg";
  cell4.src = "./_mat/portfolio_g1_t1_c4.jpg";
  showSlider();
};

// Slider 02
var trigger2 = document.getElementById("trigger2");
trigger2.onclick = function() {
  cell1.src = "./_mat/gallery2/g2p2.png";
  cell2.src = "URL";
  cell3.src = "URL";
  cell4.src = "URL";
  showSlider();
};

///////////////I've removed Slider 3-7 ;)

// Slider 08
var trigger8 = document.getElementById("trigger8");
trigger8.onclick = function() {
  cell1.src = "URL";
  cell2.src = "URL";
  cell3.src = "URL";
  cell4.src = "URL";
  showSlider();
};

// Slider 9
var trigger9 = document.getElementById("trigger9");
trigger9.onclick = function() {
  cell1.src = "URL";
  cell2.src = "URL";
  cell3.src = "URL";
  cell4.src = "URL";
  showSlider();
};

//function to hide modal and overlay
function hideSlider() {
  dark.style.visibility = "hidden";
  modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.body.style.overflowY = "visible";
  flkty.reloadCells();
}

//function to show modal and overlay
function showSlider() {
  dark.style.visibility = "visible";
  modal.style.visibility = "visible";
  document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of overthinking, I've found a solution.

1. The var "flkty" wasn't defined.

   `var flkty = new Flickity(".carousel");`
2. Finally, I've used the following solution to select the first cell. Found the API documentation here: https://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html

   `flkty.select(0, false, true);`